# Segmentation fault when reconnecting to SQL Server database using pyodbc on Linux using MS ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc, segmentation-fault, pyodbc

I have written a job server that runs 1 or more jobs concurrently (or simultaneously depending on the number of CPUs on the system). A lot of the jobs created connect to a SQL Server database, perform a query, fetch the results and write the results to a CSV file. For these types of jobs I use `pyodbc` and Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux to connect, run the query, then disconnect.

Each job runs as a separate process using the python multiprocessing module. The job server itself is kicked off as a double forked background process.

This all ran fine until I noticed today that the first SQL Server job ran fine but the second seemed to hang (i.e. look as though it was running forever).

On further investigation I noticed the process for this second job had become zombified so I ran a manual test as follows:

```
[root@myserver jobserver]# python

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22) 

[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=MY-DATABASE-SERVER;DATABASE=MY-DATABASE;UID=MY-ID;PWD=MY-PASSWORD')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('select * from my_table')

<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x1d373f0>

r = c.fetchall()

len(r)

19012

c.close()

conn.close()

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=MY-DATABASE-SERVER;DATABASE=MY-DATABASE;UID=MY-ID;PWD=MY-PASSWORD')

Segmentation fault
```

So as you can see the first connection to the database works fine but any subsequent attempts to connect fail with a segmentation fault.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this has started happening or the solution, all worked fine before today and no code has been changed.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem and in my case the solution was to upgrade the ODBC driver on the machine I was trying to make the connection from. I'm afraid I don't know much about why that fixed the problem. I suspect something was changed or upgraded on the database server I was trying to connect to.

This answer might be too late for the OP but I wanted to share it anyway since I found this question while I was troubleshooting the problem and was a little discouraged when I didn't see any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot detail the specifics of the underlying mechanics behind this problem. I can however say that the problem was being caused by using the Queue class in python's multiprocessing module. Whether I was implementing this Queue correctly remains unanswered but it appears the queue was not terminating the sub process (and the underlying database connection) properly after each job completed which led to the segmentation faults.

To solve this I implemented my own queuing system which was basically a list of Process objects executed in the order they were put into the list. A loop then made periodic checks on the status of those processes until all had completed. The next batch of jobs would then be retrieved and executed.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem recently. My config includes unixODBC-2.3.0 plus MS ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux. After some experiments, we speculate that the problem may arise due to database upgrade (to SQLServer 2008 SP1 in our case), thus triggering some bugs in the MS ODBC driver. The problem also occurs in this thread:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/23fafa84-d333-45ac-8bd0-4b76151e8bcc/sql-server-driver-for-linux-causes-segmentation-fault?forum=sqldataaccess

I also tried upgrade my driver manager to unixODBC-2.3.2 but with no luck. My final solution is using FreeTDS 0.82.6+ with unixODBC-2.3.2. This version of FreeTDS driver goes badly along with unixODBC-2.3.0, for the manager keeps complaining about function non-support of the driver. Everything goes smooth if unixODBC is upgraded.